# How to find the cluster in email

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I am doing a machine learning project and I have the dataset that contains the frequency of words that occurred in the email. I need to find the clusters that each mail belongs to. What I did is that I loaded a data into pandas dataframe, then I trained a KMeans algorithm. 
The dataset looks like following:

```
[
    {
        "adwords": 2,
        "google": 4,
        "ads": 2,
        "facebook": 1,
        "shyam": 2
    },
    {
        "facebook": 4,
        "post": 2,
        "is": 1,
        "comment": 2,
        "likes": 1,
        "google": 1
    },...]
```

Then my python code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_json('data.json', orient='records')
data = data.fillna(0)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++')
kmeans.fit_predict(data)
```

Now since I have only 30 emails and I need to cluster them according to the words given, I cannot also split into train test set. Is this a right approach to solve the problem. Please suggest what algorithm would do best and what I should be doing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You usually do *not* perform any kind of splitting/cross validation in clustering. Simply because the algorithm does not have labels anyway, so it does not as easily overfit, and you cannot easily do hyperparameter optimization.

However, you need to carefully consider data preprocessing, and in particular when working with text data, k-meane is not a good choice: 1. some text may not belong to any cluster at all (it may be atypical) 2. some text may belong to multiple clusters (e.g., Donald Trump ranting against kneeling NFL players = politics *and* sports). Neither case is well handled by k-means.

Answer (score 1):

@rabin-poudyal, Please note, *"Data splitting/cross validation has NOTHING to do with labelled or unlabelled"* dataset. On the contrary cross validation has been applied in clustering in both research and practice. See these papers for reference, [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02658.pdf),[2](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/106186005X59243),[3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370299000946), [4](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008940618127) and many more. Also see this discussion on [SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95453/cross-validation-for-comparing-clustering-techniques)

As earlier pointed out, k-means works only for continuous data. Since your dealing with text data, suggest to use any other clustering algorithm that can work with categorical data for instance, [k-medoids](http://www.math.le.ac.uk/people/ag153/homepage/KmeansKmedoids/Kmeans_Kmedoids.html)